# IP address locates on a port but DNS is not

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns

I've setup my dns on godaddy with digitalocean server as like below

```
A        @        server_ip
cname    www      @
A        abc      server_ip
```

when I'm tring to connect to a port like server_ip:33333 using server_ip in works fine but if I use abc.example.com:33333 it failed to connect. Here is my etc host configuration

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.1.1 abc.example.com abc
server ip abc.example.com abc
```

Comment: Could you test that DNS is resolving? Run: `nslookup abc.example.com`

Comment: abc.example.com works fine.

Comment: Which service are you using on port 33333? If it is apache web server, make sure that you add the domain with ServerAlias for the VirtualHost.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici I'm using nginx server

Comment: @Slipeer for FQDN I use that

Comment: You need to add the abc.example.com to  `server_name`. See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: Problem solved automatically. Dont know how.

Comment: @nikolas: automatically = nscd purge host cache. You can do it by hand: `nscd -i hosts`